# Adapting old Javascript/jQuery code to work with different JSON format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a javascript/jQuery script that takes json objects and then does something with them in a table

Here is the relevant bit of the JS/jQuery

```
        $.getJSON("People.json",
                function(data) {
                    content = '<tr>';
                    content += '<tbody>';
                    $.each(data.People, function(i, PersonObj) {
                        var Person = PersonObj[Object.keys(PersonObj)[0]];
```

this snippet was taking JSON objects from the follwing format,

```
{
"People": [
    {
        "Person1": {
            "Op": "5709",
            "Name": "Persons name",
            "WorkHours": 5,
            "Start": " 3:00PM",
            "End": " 8:00PM",
            "Clock": false,
            "OFF": false,
            "ON": false,
            "OUT": false,
            "Late": 23484360,
            "Home": 23484660,
            "HomeEarly": 23484660,
            "DifHours": 0,
            "Shift": "254"
        }
    },
    {
        "Person2": {
            "Op": "5703",
            "Name": "Persons name",
            "WorkHours": 12.25,
            "Start": " 7:45PM",
            "End": " 8:00AM",
            "Clock": false,
            "OFF": false,
            "ON": false,
            "OUT": false,
            "Late": 23484645,
            "Home": 23483940,
            "HomeEarly": 23483940,
            "DifHours": 0,
            "Shift": "251"
        }
    }
```

Here is the new format

```
[
{
    "Op": "5709",
    "Name": "Persons name",
    "WorkHours": 5,
    "Start": " 3:00PM",
    "End": " 8:00PM",
    "Clock": false,
    "OFF": false,
    "ON": false,
    "OUT": false,
    "Late": 23484360,
    "Home": 23484660,
    "HomeEarly": 23484660,
    "DifHours": 0,
    "Shift": "254"
},
{
    "Op": "5703",
    "Name": "Persons name",
    "WorkHours": 12.25,
    "Start": " 7:45PM",
    "End": " 8:00AM",
    "Clock": false,
    "OFF": false,
    "ON": false,
    "OUT": false,
    "Late": 23484645,
    "Home": 23483940,
    "HomeEarly": 23483940,
    "DifHours": 0,
    "Shift": "251"
}
```

how can i get the JS/JQuery to work w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could simply handle data as a field, since there are no other declarations on top of the JSON:

```
 $.getJSON("People.json",
     function(data) {
         content = '<tr>';
         content += '<tbody>';
         for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
             var person = data[i]; 
             var op = person.Op; 
             var name = person.Name; 
             // etc...
         }
         ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write a simple conversion function that takes your existing data and returns a new clean set:

```
function convert(data) {
  var people = data.People;
  var out = [];
  for (var i = 0, l = people.length; i < l; i++) {
    var person = people[i];
    var key = Object.keys(person);
    out.push(person[key]);
  }
  return out;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9bzuprv5/1/)